# Parameterize an equation

Tags: calculus, parametric, parametrization

The equation is:

$$x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 3 = 0$$

How do I parameterize that? I haven't encountered equations with both $x^2$, $y^2$ and $x$ before and therefore I am not sure of how to handle the problem.

Should I break out an $x$ to form $y^2+x(x-2)=3$ ?

Comment: Try completing the square in x. The equation should then have a very familiar structure.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=2^2$$
So it's a circle centered at $(1,0)$ and with radius $2$.

So,
$$x=1+2\cos\theta$$
$$y=2\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation $(x-1)^2+y^2=2^2$ then it is paramaterised as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=1+ 2\cos( \theta) \\
y= 2 \sin ( \theta). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: shouldnt it equal 4?

Answer (score 0):

A *rational parametrisation*:

The equation describes the circle of radius $2$, centred at $(1,0)$. It passes through the point $(-1,0)$. Let's cut the circle with a variable straight line of slope $t$ passing through this point. An equation of this straight line is $\; y=t(x+1)$ and the abscissæ of its intersections with the circle are the roots of the quadratic equation:
$$x^2+t^2(x+1)^2-2x-3=0\iff(1+t^2)x^2+2(t^2-1)x+t^2-3=0.$$
One of these roots is $-1$, so the other root is the opposite of their product $\smash[b]{\dfrac{t^2-3}{1+t^2}}$, whence the parametrisation:
\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{3-t^2}{1+t^2},\\y=t(x+1)=\dfrac{4t}{1+t^2}.\end{cases}